# How to call the same datepicker on 2 different input fields

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) and I have a situation where I need to call the datepicker in the input field 2 or more times,but the problem is that,the datepicker opens on the first input filed,but on the rest it won't.
I tried changing the ID of the input and the datepicker script,still won't work.
Please help.
Thx in advance

Code:

```
<div class='form-group'>                                    
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-12 date">
            <label>Label1</label>
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
                    <input id='input' type="text" value=' <?php echo $var; ?>' 
                    class="form-control" name="dateRangePicker" required />
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div><!-- end input group -->
        </div><!-- end col-xs-12 date --> 
    </div><!-- end row -->  

        <input type='checkbox'>
        <label>Data not available</label>
        </div><!-- end form-group -->

        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Label2</label>
            <input id='input' type='text' class='form-control' value=' <?php echo $var;  ?>' name="dateRangePicker2" id="dateRangePicker2">


</div><!-- end form-group -->
```

SCRIPT
Note:I duplicated the code below,while i changed the id from dateRangePicker to dateRangePicker2,and it still wouldn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#dateRangePicker')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            startDate: '01.01.2000',
            endDate: '31.12.2020'
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // Revalidate the date field
            $('#dateRangeForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
        });

    $('#dateRangeForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            date: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Message1'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                        min: '01.01.2000',
                        max: '31.12.2020',
                        message: 'Message2'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: ID of an element must be unique... so if you have multiple elements with the id `dateRangePicker`, the it will work only for the first item

Comment: Use `dateRangePicker` as class and use class selector

Comment: well you have declared two ids for same field in second input box... one at beginning id='input' and other at end id="dateRangePicker2".... remove the first one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your HTML. You are using attribute ID for two times. id="input" and one more id . Here below

> ```
>  <input id='input' type='text' class='form-control' value=' <?php echo $var;  ?>' name="dateRangePicker2" id="dateRangePicker2">
> ```

Try Below code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#inputOne,#inputTwo')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            startDate: '01.01.2000',
            endDate: '31.12.2020',
         orientation: "top auto"
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // Revalidate the date field
            $('#dateRangeForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
        });

    
});
```

```html
<div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-12 date">
            <label>Label1</label>
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
                    <input id='inputOne' type="text" class="form-control dateRangePicker2" name="dateRangePicker" required />
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div><!-- end input group -->
        </div><!-- end col-xs-12 date --> 
    </div><!-- end row -->  

       <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-xs-12 date">
            <label>Label1</label>
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
                    <input id='inputTwo' type="text" class="form-control dateRangePicker2" name="dateRangePicker" required />
                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div><!-- end input group -->
        </div><!-- end col-xs-12 date --> 
    </div><!-- end row -->
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/ajjLyd57/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` not `ID` like below:

```
 $('.dateRangePicker')...
```

Comment: Still won't work,the first one works normal,but not the second one still won't cooperate